# scipy linregress: computing only scaling/slope parameter with intercept fixed at 0

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression

I am trying to use [scipy.stats.linregress](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) to compute a scaling factor between two sets of data in the least square sense. However, it gives me an intercept despite the fact that the input `xi` variable is a vector and not a `n X 2` matrix.

So, a simple code is as follows:

```
from scipy import stats
from numpy import arrange,array

y = [0, 11, 19, 28, 41, 49, 62, 75, 81]
xi = arange(0,9)

scale, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xi,y)
```

Running this, I get the scale as 10.383 but I also get an intercept of -0.86. How can I tell it to fit only the scaling parameter and the intercept should be kept zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to fit a model, `y~xi` without intercept, you may want to consider using more statistic oriented package such as `statsmodels`:

```
In [17]:

import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
y = [0, 11, 19, 28, 41, 49, 62, 75, 81]
xi = np.arange(0,9)
model = sm.OLS(y, xi)
results = model.fit()
In [18]:

print results.params
[ 10.23039216]
```

You can verify the result independently using `R`. Only that now you have to explicitly specify the intercept to be 0:

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
y <- c(0, 11, 19, 28, 41, 49, 62, 75, 81)
model1 <- lm(y~x+0)
summary(model1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6912 -1.4608  0.0000  0.6176  3.3873 

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
x   10.230      0.129   79.29 7.14e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.843 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9987,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9986 
F-statistic:  6286 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 7.14e-13
```

The calculation under the hood is simple:

```
In [29]:

import scipy.optimize as so
so.fmin(lambda b, x, y: ((b*x-y)**2).sum(), x0=0.1, args=(xi, y))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 27.171569
         Iterations: 27
         Function evaluations: 54
Out[29]:
array([ 10.23039063])
```

Comment: I was hoping to stay within the bumpy/scipy domain but I guess this will save me some headache :)

Comment: The last solution will do..., if you are willing to get `scipy.optimize` involved. That way you are still in `numpy`/`scipy` domain. Of course you have to write a few lines of code for `p-value` `R-square` etc, which will be extra amount of work.

Comment: For naive fitting (i.e. you don't care about R, p, etc), you can use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit(lambda x, m: m*x, xi, y)`